# how do i create a tkinter mixin as a singleton

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, singleton, mixins

I am trying to create a collection of re-usable Forms using python3 tkinter, using a mixin for common methods such as menu commands etc. As the mixin is used in most components it appears to create several separate instances of the mixin class but my attempts to turn the mixin into a singleton fail with `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

I'm an old cobol programmer who started this project to try and get my head around oop - this is making my head hurt

I have added an intervening base class that should strip out the args to no effect.

```
PROGRAM_NAME = "GuiMenuMixin"

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): pass

class GuiMenuMixin(Base):

    _singleton = None
    def __new__(cls,*args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._singleton:
            cls._singleton = super().__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
        return cls._singleton

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.initialProgramName
        except AttributeError: 
             try:
                self.programName  
                self.initialProgramName = self.programName   
            except AttributeError: 
                self.programName = PROGRAM_NAME

# pretty basic mixin stuff follows

# sample usage which fails

class SimpleTitleBarFrame(Frame, GuiMenuMixin):

    def __init__(self, parent=None,  **args):

        super().__init__(parent, **args)

        try: self.programName
        except AttributeError: self.programName = PROGRAM_NAME

        GuiMenuMixin.__init__(self)

        self.parent=parent

############## stuff removed


        leftMenu = SimpleMenuBarFrame(self, menuSpec=self.menuSpec, style="BW.TLabel")
        leftMenu.grid(row=0,column=6,sticky=W)
        self.columnconfigure(6, weight=0)


        rightIcons = SimpleIconBarFrame(self, iconSpec=self.iconSpec)
        rightIcons.grid(row=0,column=10,sticky=W)
        self.columnconfigure(10, weight=0)


#### This runs ok as it does not call any child frames utilising the mixin

PROGRAM_NAME = "SimpleMenuBarFrame"

class SimpleMenuBarFrame(Frame, GuiMenuMixin,):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **args):
        super().__init__(parent, **args)

        try:
            self.programName                                                     
        except AttributeError: 
            self.programName = PROGRAM_NAME

        GuiMenuMixin.__init__(self)

        self.menuBar = self.makeMenu(menuSpec=self.menuSpec)
```

*Error:*

> `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

Comment: Thanks Stovfl, Because I have only posted fragments of code it perhaps is not clear that self.initialProgramName is an attribute rather than a function. I have been trying to use instance variables shared with themixin to avoid excessive parameter passing.

Comment: *"is an attribute rather than a function"*: What do you want to accomplish doing `try: self.initialProgramName; except AttributeError:`?